# Getting results from thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Im learning multi-threading, and im having trouble getting the results form a thread that implements Runnable. My code looks something like this:

```
 public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
  String result;
  public void run (){
    //calculcate result
  }
  public String getResult(){
    return result;
  }
}
```

and:

```
  public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
       Thread mine = new Thread (new MyRunnable());
       mine.start();
       mine.join();
       mine.getResult(); //This does not work
    }
  }
```

mine.getResult() does not work, since 'mine' is Thread, but i cannot make 'mine' MyRunnable either. I think extending Thread instead of implementing Runnable would solve the issue, but my teacher said we shouldnt do it.

I need result in main because i need to write it to file along with result2 from MyRunnable2 (completely different task than MyRunnable)

Any ideas how to get the result?

Comment: You need to keep a reference to the `new MyThread()` object, and use that reference later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyThread runnable = new MyThread();
    Thread mine = new Thread(runnable);
    mine.start();
    mine.join();
    runnable.getResult();
}
```

A piece of advice: give `MyThread` a different name for it's a `Runnable` and it could be mistaken for a `Thread`.